# Store history in database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, dictionary, cursor

I want to store history data in a sqlite db.
a max of 20 "entries" should be secured.

when adding a new entrie the oldest should be deleted and the new one added at the begining of the list. 
when calling the histroy i want it to be shown in reversed order (latest entry first)

as far as i know that functionality is not possible with a cursor by itself. i will need to convert the cursor i call into another MAP type. the question is which one and how to realize that actions.

Comment: Why not just handle all of this in the function which add's elements to your db?

Comment: of course. the question is how that function could look like. for example i have no idea how to realize a replacement of the oldest value in a "easy" way. of course i could store the date +time as string in the db and convert it back on every add / request event and then use some sort to sort by date. but that would happen with EVERY SINGLE action which is kinda much overhead!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should not be that hard. Your table for the history needs an id column. It is also mandatory when working with cursors and adapters. Define the id column as [auto incremented](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp). So every time you insert a new row into the table the new row gets automatically an unique id which is higher than the last id that was assigned to row that was inserted before.

You must write a method which you call when you want to add a new entry to the database. Within the method you do the following.

1. Check the number of items in the database table.

   - If there are less than 20 entries do nothing.
   - If there are more or equal than 20 entries, then query for the row with the [lowest id](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_min.asp) and delete it.
2. Add the new entry to the database. It will automatically get the highest id of all rows in the table.

When you want to display the entries in a list using a cursor you can define the order of the returned rows by the SQL command [order by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp).

Comment: thats what i was looking for! i'm are of all that sql commands, but since i work really rarely with sql i didn't think of it! thanks!

Comment: Will there be an auto assignment for the id? Since the row with the lowest id will be deleted there would be a gap. Or is this issue also handled by the delete method?

Comment: Databases normally have different modes of auto increment. Normally each row gets an id which is higher than any other id that has ever been assigned to any row int the table. So when when you have 4 rows in the table, delete row with id 2 and insert a new one, the new row will get the id of 5 or higher. There are other modes where ids of deleted rows can be reused or where the id are not only unique for a single table  but also for the whole database. But I think [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) only  offers the first mode i mentioned.

Comment: hmm ok for the count i can use something like 
`String sql = "SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT " + HISTORY_ID + ") FROM " + HISTORY_TABLE;
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);`
But how do i get the count from the cursor? whats the colum name of such a request?

Comment: When you query the db withe this SQL command, then you get a cursor which will contain one result row. The result row will be of the type int. Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT " + HISTORY_ID + ") FROM " + HISTORY_TABLE, null); int count = 0;
    while(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        count = cursor.getInt(0);
    } The count variable will contain the number of rows in the table.